# Reading mails and from java using IMAP protocol but missing some file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm working on project in spring boot, where I need read details of the mails.

First I'm storing unread mails into message[] array and I'm reading first 50 mails and again next 50 mails and so on.

But when I do so some of the mails are missing out i.e., in 50 mails some number of mails are not read and details are not recorded.

Below is the function where I am doing all this operations.

Please help me to improve my code.

```
public List<Object> read(){

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.host", "imap.gmail.com");
    properties.setProperty("mail.port", "995");
    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "imaps");
    String userName=resourceBundle.getString("mailUserName");
    String password=resourceBundle.getString("mailPassword");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
            new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect();
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        SearchTerm recentTerm = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.RECENT), true);
        SearchTerm fromTerm = new FromTerm(new InternetAddress(resourceBundle.getString("receiveMailFrom")));
        SearchTerm unreadTerm = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
        SearchTerm subjectTerm = new SubjectTerm(this.subjectTerm);
        SearchTerm subjectAndUnreadTerm = new AndTerm(subjectTerm, unreadTerm);
        SearchTerm recentAndFromTerm = new AndTerm(recentTerm, fromTerm);
        SearchTerm subjectAndUnreadAndFromTerm = new AndTerm(subjectAndUnreadTerm, fromTerm);
        Message messages[] = inbox.search(subjectAndUnreadAndFromTerm);
        List<Object> readParams=new ArrayList<>();
        if (messages.length<count)
        logger.info("Number of mails = " + messages.length);
        else
            logger.info("Number of mails = " + count);


        for (Message message : messages) {
            if(mailcount<count) {
                Address[] from = message.getFrom();
                logger.info("-------------------------------");
                logger.info("Date : " + message.getSentDate());
                logger.info("From : " + from[0]);
                logger.info("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                logger.info("Content :");
                fileNames = processMessageBody(message);
                logger.info("--------------------------------");
                mailcount +=1;

            }
            else{
                break;
            }

        }

        inbox.close(true);
        store.close();
        if(messages.length==0)
        {
            readParams.add(0);
            return readParams;
        }
        else {
            readParams.add(1);
            readParams.add(fileNames);
            return readParams;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This really isn't enough detail to reproduce or reason about the problem...

Comment: @arnt what details is required? i can provide

Comment: Do the same messages fail every time, or different ones? What is peculiar about the failing messages, can you give an example of a failing message?

Comment: If you're using port 995, you're not using IMAP.  Are you sure you're not using 993?

Comment: What does processMessagebodies do?  An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help too.

Comment: @Max yes i am not using 993 port.

Comment: @arnt whenever i run the code and test suppose i'll send 300 mails at a time, i.e., in message[] array 300 mails will be present. But i am not reading all 300 mails at a time I am grouping them into 50 mails. So when i read every 50 mails around 5 to 6 mails details are not recorded for each 50 mails.